# FileWriter method is only writing last line

Tags: java, arrays, filewriter

I have a fileWrite() method that accepts two string values as parameters(specific array values). I include this method in a for loop so it can loop through the array and get the string values to write to the file

```
public void writeFile(String ip, String vals) {

    try {

         bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("Finished.txt"));

        bw.write(ip + ": " + vals );
        bw.newLine();


        bw.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

and where i include the method in my code looks as follows:

```
for (int i = 0 ; i  < address.length ; i++) {
writeFile(address[i][0], address[i][1]);
        }
```

it seems only to write the last values in the array to the text file.

Comment: Did one of the answers below answer your question? Please select one as the solution!

Answer (score 3):

You are overwriting the file on every call to

```
new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("Finished.txt"));
```

You are better off opening the file once, writing all your data, and then closing it.

Comment: Well... complete the answer! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Like @climbage said, you're overwriting your file.

I would suggest one of two solutions:

1) Pass the BufferedWriter by reference and change the function name to writeLineToFile (for clarity):

```
void callingFunction()
{
   <<get line>>
   bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("Finished.txt"));
   writeLineToFile(bw, ip, vals);
   bw.close();
}

void writeLineToFile (BufferedWriter &bw, String ip, String vals)
{
   <<do something>>
}
```

or

2) Group the entire file to be written into an array of Strings and pass that to the function:

```
void writeFile (std::vector<String> &ip, std::vector<String> &vals)
{
   <<check that vectors are same size>>
   int len = ip.size();

   bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("Finished.txt"));
   for (int i=0; i < len; ++i)
   {
      <<do something>>
   }
   bw.close();
}
```

Comment: Note: There are several ways you could iterate over the vectors...I just chose the simplest; however, you should ensure that the vectors are the same size. Better yet, concatenate the strings before the write function and pass a single vector.

Answer (score 0):

use another constructor in loop

```
FileWriter(File file,
              boolean append)
```

or better

1. open once
2. write
3. free resource

Answer (score 0):

use a for loop to write it all in one open something like :

```
try
{
 int length = ip.size();

 bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("Finished.txt"));
 for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
 {
      writeLineToFile(bw, ip, vals);
 }
 bw.close();
}
```